# jquery ajax JSON parse error firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

So this one is very strange.  My application has a ton of ajax calls, but for some reason only one of them doesn't work in Firefox. It works in other browsers.

I checked the network tab and the headers are sent as normal, but there is no response when I check the response tab. The error message that comes up  from the error callback reads:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Again, it works fine in chrome and IE and I have a bunch of other similar ajax calls that work in Firefox.  What could be the problem?

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php_helpers/pnm_profile_helper.php',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: (data),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        (code)
    },
    error: function(s, error, errorThrown){
         alert(s+'\n'+ error+'\n'+ errorThrown);
     }
});
```

the response I'm supposed to get (and I do get in other browsers) is

```
{"gpa":"3.5","credits":"30"}
```

Comment: that means the json you are returning is not valid.... may be there is an unescaped new line character in it... can you share a sample response using the network tab of your browser tools

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to determine what's wrong with the data being returned

Comment: Please provide the json response sample that you are getting

Comment: like i said in the post, there is no response when i check the response tab.  The response i'm supposed to be getting (and what i do get on other browsers) is: {"gpa":"3.5","credits":"30"}

Comment: Did you solve this one? I'm having the same issue, only in firefox 45, 46 and 47...